# using wireless with LAN connection active

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, wireless-networking, network-adapter

Is it possible to run a wireless connection but still remain connected to your local lan?
The desktop has wireless and i wanna use wireshark locally to mess around on my wireless but want to remain connected to my GBLAN for the speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible but Windows prefers the network you selected in the advanced network options. You can use tools like [ForceBindIP](http://www.r1ch.net/stuff/forcebindip/) to force the use of one connection.

> ForceBindIP is a freeware Windows application that will inject itself into another 
>   application and alter how certain Windows Sockets calls are made,
>   allowing you to force the other application to use a specific network
>   interface / IP address. This is useful if you are in an environment
>   with multiple interfaces and your application has no such option for
>   binding to a specific interface.*

Comment: so what i am basically doing is just forcing wireshark to use the wireless connection? i assume that connection is active just not being used?

Comment: In Wireshark doesnt it let you choose the Interface to listen on? http://www.google.com/imgres?q=wireshark+interface&um=1&hl=en&sa=N&tbo=d&biw=1920&bih=928&tbm=isch&tbnid=IJMQXtoRt15cgM:&imgrefurl=http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/tutorials/wa-tomcat/section4.html&docid=tRf-Wv6Fmt8uFM&imgurl=http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/tutorials/wa-tomcat/fig003.jpg&w=500&h=239&ei=dYXkUP-vO4GG2wXk1oCYCA&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=391&vpy=146&dur=330&hovh=155&hovw=325&tx=136&ty=49&sig=110190264918940527589&page=1&tbnh=137&tbnw=288&start=0&ndsp=41&ved=1t:429,r:2,s:0,i:96

Comment: j_bombay posted a picture which shows that the tool allows you to select the interface. For other application use this ForceBindIP.